# Update Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have two custom controls of the same type. By selecting item from first one i need to update item source of the second one but it doesn't update the UI.

```
                        <common:ListViewSelectorView Grid.Column="1"
                                                     Margin="8,0"
                                                     Items="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedCategories, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        <common:ListViewSelectorView Grid.Column="2"
                                                     Margin="8,0"
                                                     Items="{Binding Products, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                     SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedProducts, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Here's Dependency Properties:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ListViewSelectorView), new PropertyMetadata(null));             

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ListViewSelectorView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I implimented CollectionChanged event for category selected items and then fill the Products, but it doesn't update the ui.

appreciate for any help.

Comment: The xaml and dependency property declarations don't help much in figuring out what is wrong, show relevant code to the CollectionChanged event handler.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of the `Products/SelectedProducts` properties? And to emphasize the previous comment: Please provide the code that you use to fill the Products as well.

Comment: Try adding UpdateSourceTrigger to the binding. Here is an example: `Binding SelectedCategories, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`